# Rename [fab] to [android-fab]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would like to suggest to change the tag **[fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab)** to **[android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab)** since it is only being used for question regarding android development and it is not likely that it will be used for something different than stuff regarding Android

Comment: And more importantly, if it ever is used for something else, the two uses should be distinguished.

Comment: I see a few questions referencing [tag:android] and more referencing [tag:fabric] as well as other unrelated tools called fab, [tag:fab] would probably be better off removed