# The [FAB] tag is floating everywhere?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

> **Edit:**
>   *I (and I think more people) would really like to do something about this tag problem, but without people posting their suggestions and
>   people voting on them I/we can't really decide what to do. The
>   comments are really helpful though.*

I noticed that there are three separate tags ([fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab), [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button), [android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab)) for the same Material Design UI phenomenon: The Floating Action Button.

- [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) has no wiki, has 293 questions, 232 of those are also tagged
  with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).
- [android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab) has wiki, has 49 questions (all tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)).
- [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button)  has wiki, has 810 questions, 769 of
  those are also tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

The Floating Action Button is not especially an Android only UI element, it's part of the Material Design Guideline. So should the tag [android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab) be burned? Currently almost all questions regarding the FAB are Android related.

Also [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) is just an acronym of [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button), these two tags should be merged or at least be synonyms. Right?

*Summary: What's up with these three "floating" tags…? What is the correct way to handle them?*

Comment: I'd say [tag:fab] and [tag:android-fab] should be synonymed to [tag:floating-action-button] to avoid further creation of the tags after they are emptied. Though you may get some backlash because the android people like to have [android-everything] style tags. See: [`is:q [android-*]`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bandroid-*%5D)

Comment: As noted in [this partial duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281642/359284), [tag:fab] is also used for [tag:fabric] for some reason. I'm more in favor of burninating [tag:fab] rather than making it a synonym of [tag:android-fab].

Comment: @KevinBrown the "some reason" is undoubtedly that the CLI utility for fabric is `fab`. It's like tagging a mercurial question with [tag:hg] (which is synonymed). Since fab is ambiguous, I agree getting rid of it is probably best.

Comment: [tag:fabric], meanwhile, is also horribly ambiguous - the wiki mentions Python, but a lot of the questions are about either Android or JS

Comment: @hobbs: If you can get it blacklisted, sure. Otherwise, second-best is synonymizing it to something more unambiguous.

Comment: Almost two years later, this question still stands and needs new life.

Answer (score 3):

Even if nothing else in this question gets done, we've confirmed that [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) is a bit too ambiguous, and the missing tag wiki isn't helping. **So I propose we burninate [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab).**

This question has actually [come up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281642/359284) with [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) and [android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab), here's the comment I left there almost exactly a year ago.

> I see a few questions referencing [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and more referencing [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) as well as other unrelated tools called fab, [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) would probably be better off removed
>
> -- [Kevin Brown, Jan 3 '15](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281642/rename-fab-to-android-fab#comment136793_281642)

At the time there weren't nearly as many [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions as there now is in [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab).